# Strange behaviour of list.remove()

Tags: python-2.7

Consider the following piece of code.

```
def foo(a):
    b = [a+9*i+j for i in xrange(0,3) for j in xrange(0,3)]
    return b.remove(a)
```

The code doesn't work. It returns an `null`. But if I do the following, it works.

```
def foo1(a):
    return [a+9*i+j for i in xrange(0,3) for j in xrange(0,3)]

b = foo1(a)
b = b.remove(a) # This works
```

Why does the first snippet fail when the second one works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.remove(...)` does not return any value. According to official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

> You might have noticed that methods like `insert`, `remove` or `sort` that only modify the list have no return value printed – they return the default `None`. This is a design principle for all mutable data structures in Python.